# Removing mouseenter event on dynamically created elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-events

I'm having some trouble with my Javascript when using jQuery UI's sortable method on dynamically created elements. When I hover an image it displays a larger version of the image which follows the cursor within the thumbnail. Then, when I'm sorting/dragging an image it displays the larger image with it's position set to far away from the thumbnail. The larger image should be hidden when sorting :-)

I've made a screenr so it's easier for you to see what I mean: http://screenr.com/jjv8

My code for hooking up the events:

```
// Selected photos hover
$('ul li img').live('mouseenter', function () {
    var img = $(this);
    var imgDiv = $(this).parent().find('.hover-image');
    img.mousemove(function (e) {
        imgDiv.show();
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY - 50;
        imgDiv.css({ "top": y + "px", "left": x + "px" });
    });
});

$('ul li img').live('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.hover-image').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

And my code for sorting:

```
selectedPhotosList.sortable({
    handle: '.selected-thumbnail-image',
    start: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.find('.selected-thumbnail-image').die('mouseenter');
        ui.item.find('.hover-image').hide();
    }
});
```

Yes, I'm using `.live()` since this is a datatype which resides in Umbraco CMS which uses an older version of jQuery, so `.on()` doesn't work :-)

Anyone got a hint on how to get this to work?

**EDIT**

I found the bug:

In my `.live('mouseenter', function()`... I'm calling `imgDiv.show();` every time the cursor moves.

Doing it like this works:

```
// Selected photos hover
$('ul li img').live('mouseenter', function () {
    var img = $(this);
    var imgDiv = $(this).parent().find('.hover-image');
    imgDiv.show();
     img.mousemove(function (e) {
         var x = e.pageX;
         var y = e.pageY - 50;
         imgDiv.css({ "top": y + "px", "left": x + "px" });
     });
});

$('ul li img').live('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.hover-image').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

However, this creates another bug when using IE.: Screenr: http://screenr.com/1Iv8

The hover image is shown once before actually triggering the mousemove function :-/ Any way to overrule this?

Comment: Just a side-note: `delegate()`/`undelegate()` have been added in jQuery 1.4.2, replacing `live()`/`die()`. This doesn't mean `live` is not going to work off course. A benefit of `delegate` over `live` is that `delegate` lets you bind to the `closest` static element, thus event bubbling is only going up to that defined element while `live` will always bubble all the way up to the document.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl delegate() doesn't have any effect here it seems :-/ Tried all of the "event binders" and only live() seems to be working, for some reason.

Comment: I only mentioned `delegate` because you noted that you can't use `on` due to your older version of jQuery. That's all. It was purely for information purposes, not a suggestion to a fix.

Comment: I understand that :-) and I learned something new about event bubbling. Just tried it to see if it made any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

`$('ul li img').off('mouseenter');`

Answer (score 0):

.die() should work for you. [Read the documentation on it](http://api.jquery.com/die/)

```
$('ul li img').die('mouseenter');
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: Well that is what he used, isn't it?

Comment: @Veltar I tried the die() method, but no result. I've updated my question with a fix and new bug ;-)

Comment: @bomortensen: If you found a fix for your current question, post it as an `answer` and accept it. If you have a new issue now, post it as a separate question. Going from one issue to the next in a single post is not practical and is not going to be useful to any person in future having a similar issue you had to start with when reading through this thread.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl can't really say it was a fix since it lead to another bug in IE. So basically, no solution is found yet :-(

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this which works in IE7+, Chrome and Firefox, although it's a bit ugly (not sure if that is an understatement ;-)):

In the sortable start event I create a copy of the hover-image and store it in a variable then removing it from the DOM. Then in the stop event I prepend it to the listitem that has been dragged/sorted. Code:

```
var tempHoverImage = "";
selectedPhotosList.sortable({
    handle: '.selected-thumbnail-image',
    start: function (event, ui) {
        var hoverImage = ui.item.find('.hover-image');
        tempHoverImage = hoverImage;
        hoverImage.remove();
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.prepend(tempHoverImage);
    }
});
```